# Calling MySQL stored procedure in c, passing variable argument

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I made a database in MySQL and I created some Stored Procedures. Now I need to launch these SP using a C program.

I've already connected my db to c successfully, using:

```
char u[255];
char p[255];

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    scanf("%s",u);
    scanf("%s",p);
    
    conn = mysql_init (NULL);
    login = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost",u,p, "ASL", 3306, NULL, 0);
}
```

I'm able to calling a SP without any parameter. For example my SP `mostra_pazienti()`shows all the rows contained in the MySQL table 'paziente', and I made in this way:

```
    query = "call mostra_pazienti()";
    mysql_query (conn,query);
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(conn);
    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
        {   
            printf(" %s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL"); 
        }
        printf ("\n");
        }   
    }
```

But basically now I need to run a procedure which takes some parameters as input.

For example MySQL procedure `esame_aggiungi(IN code CHAR(5),IN name VARCHAR(30),IN cost FLOAT)` insert a new row in the table exam.

So, in C, how can I take the parameters code, name, and cost using `scanf()`, and how can I use them to execute my Stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking "how do I build the `CALL MYPROC(ARG1, ARG2...)` string within my C program", you can use the function `snprintf` for that, which writes formatted data to a string of known length.

```
char query[1000];
snprintf(query, 1000, "CALL MYPROCEDURE(\"%s\", \"%s\", %f);", code, name, cost);

mysql_query(conn, query);
```

Note that bounds checking for the constraints in the MySQL table (i.e. the field `code` is of type `CHAR (5)` and `name` is of type `VARCHAR (30)`) must be taken care of as well.  A column with type `CHAR(N)` rather than `VARCHAR` will contain exactly `N` characters.

Comment: compiling this `char code[5];
  char name[30];
  float cost;
  scanf ("%s",code);
  scanf ("%s",name);
  scanf ("%f",&cost);
  printf("%s\n",code);
  printf ("%s\n",name);
  printf ("%f\n",cost);
     printf("Loggato come amministratore del sistema\n\n");
  snprintf(query, 1000, "call esame_aggiungi(\"%s\", \"%s\", %f);", code, name, cost);` it gives me segmentation fault. Can you help me?

Comment: i solved the segmentation fault. Now i have to pass the `snprintf()` result to `mysql_query(conn,<query to execute>)`

Comment: `snprintf` populates the string pointed to by the first parameter (i.e. `query`); you can use that